# Why does Typescript raise an improper property as an error for an invalid assignment?

Tags: typescript

Let's say you have the following code

```js
type Dog = {
  type: "DOG";
  bark?: boolean;
};

type Cat = {
  type: "CAT";
  meow?: boolean;
};

// Wrong RawData
type RawData = { 
  type: "DOG" | "CAT";
  bark?: number;
};

const wrongValue: Dog | Cat = {} as RawData;
```

There are manually created types such as `Dog` and `Cat` that you want to use in your business layer, and there are invalid types such as `RawData` that were created by external APIs or graphql, but do not match your business layer.

This will result in an ambiguous error like this

```
const wrongValue: Dog | Cat
Type 'RawData' is not assignable to type 'Dog | Cat'.
  Type 'RawData' is not assignable to type 'Dog'.
    Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
      Type '"DOG" | "CAT"' is not assignable to type '"DOG"'.
        Type '"CAT"' is not assignable to type '"DOG"'.(2322)
```

When I set the `type` property to `DOG` in `RawData`, I get an error saying that the `bark` property has a mismatched type, as expected.

Matching the property of `bark` in `RawData` as `boolean` will not cause an error.

What I want to do is fix the wrong `RawData` type, but the error message stumbles over the `type` property and says nothing about `bark`. If there are dozens of properties, and only one of them is wrong, it makes it extremely difficult to fix the error because it shows the error as being related to the wrong `type`. I need an error message that correctly points out the incorrect property.

Why do I get these errors? What can we do?

Comment: Maybe you should fix your code generator instead of coping with its results?

Comment: "Why do I get these errors" has an authoritative-ish answer at [ms/TS#52358](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52358), and I'm happy to write that up here.  "What can we do (to improve the errors)" is less easy to answer since, as far as I know, you can't change it without changing your types, at which point you should probably just attack the problem closer to its source as @vr. mentioned.  How should we proceed with this question?